# Fallback (default) image using Angular JS ng-src

Tags: image, angularjs, src, fallback

I'm trying to set an image source using data returned from a modal. This is inside an ng-repeat loop:

```
<div id="divNetworkGrid">
    <div id="{{network.id}}" ng-repeat="network in networks">
        <span>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="imgContainer">
                        <img ng-src="{{ ('assets/img/networkicons/'+ network.actual + '.png') || 
                                         'assets/img/networkicons/default.png' }}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As is apparent, I want to populate default.png when the network.actual model property is returned as null. But my code is not picking up the default image, though the first image is coming up fine when available.

I'm sure this is some syntax issue, but cant figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I have often wondered how to do this and have tried such things as you have, but it had never seemed to work! Good question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interesting way to use `ng-src`.  I haven't tested how that expression would be handled but I would suggest doing it a more stable way:

```
<img ng-src="{{ networkIcon }}" />
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.networkIcon = network.actual ? 'assets/img/networkicons/' + network.actual + '.png' : 'assets/img/networkicons/default.png';
```

*Edit:* Just to clarify, I'm not suggesting the best way to do this is to bind the image source directly to the scope but rather to move the image fallback logic outside of the view. In my applications I often do it in the services that retrieve the data or on the server itself and send an image URL so the client only has to worry about a single property.

*Edit to address repeater*:

```
angular.forEach($scope.networks, function(network) {
  network.icon = network.actual ? 'assets/img/networkicons/' + network.actual + '.png' : 'assets/img/networkicons/default.png';
});

<tr ng-repeat="network in networks">
  <td><img ng-src="{{ network.icon }}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I should have specified before, but network.actual is actually within an ng-repeat. network is an iteration of the networks model. So this option wouldn't work for me, unfortunately...

Comment: Yes it will, in my edit paragraph I mentioned I do it in services that retrieve the data.  So before you bind to the repeater iterate through your data and replace (or append) the image source.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how to modify the data before it hits the repeater.

Answer (score 31):

I have just found out, that you can use both `ng-src` and `src` on an `img` tag and if `ng-src` fails (variable used does not exists etc.), it will automatically fallback to `src` attribute.

Comment: I thinks solution is better if you do not want to write more code.

Answer (score 19):

What I imagine is happening is the src is returning a 404 even if `network.actual` is null. For example, first value:

`('assets/img/networkicons/'+network.actual+'.png')`

is evaluating to a 404 src URL, something like ('assets/img/networkicons/**null**.png'). So in the OR selection, it's truth-y, but the resource is 404. In that case, you can set the fallback via onError with something like:

```
<img ng-src="{{('assets/img/networkicons/'+network.actual+'.png')}}" onerror="this.src='assets/img/networkicons/default.png'" />
```

CodePen to demo use cases - http://codepen.io/jpost-vlocity/pen/zqqerL

Comment: This is perfect if the +network.actual+ var exists but the image does not!

Comment: The best solution as to me

Comment: Clean, simple and neat. Works well.

Comment: Thanks.. Elegant and simple solution.

Answer (score 15):

```
angular.module('fallback',[]).directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
    return{
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('error', function () {
                angular.element(this).attr("src", attrs.fallbackSrc);
            });
        }
    }
});

<img ng-src="{{url}}" fallback-src="default-image.jpg"/>

angular.module('fallback', []).directive('actualSrc', function () {
    return{
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('actualSrc', function(newVal, oldVal){
                 if(newVal != undefined){
                     var img = new Image();
                     img.src = attrs.actualSrc;
                     angular.element(img).bind('load', function () {
                         element.attr("src", attrs.actualSrc);
                     });
                 }
            });

        }
    }
});

<img actual-src="{{url}}" ng-src="default.jpg"/>
```

[link](http://subashselvaraj.com/2014/09/28/angularjs-fallback-image-directive/)

Comment: I was reluctant to try this initially because I thought it must be a simpler solution. However, after I tried many suggestions and none of them work perfectly, this is definitely the best one. Thanks!

Comment: @miliu Glad it helped you :)

Comment: minor error: first example should use fallback-src as the attribute html code (or fallBackSrc as the directive name). Great solution otherwise!

Answer (score 8):

```
<div id="divNetworkGrid">
                <div id="{{network.id}}" ng-repeat="network in networks">
                    <span>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="imgContainer">
                                    <img ng-src="{{'assets/img/networkicons/'+(network.actual || 'default' )+'.png'}}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The inline or will work if the the queried variable is undefined. The above will fix your issue

Answer (score 5):

You can supply the alternative image after OR operator like this:

```
{{ book.images.url || 'Images/default.gif' }}
```