# Inline CSS url() function request page URL again

Tags: html, css, angularjs

If the `url()` function in CSS is called without any parameters, does it send a request to the page's URL?

I am building an angular app and I have the following, rather naive code in my partial:

```html
<div style="background-image: url({{scope.image_url}});">
  {{scope.message_text}}
</div>
```

When the app loaded, I noticed that there was a call being made to my page's URL causing my server-side handlers to fire some analytics events incorrectly.

From my observation, I saw this behavior on Chrome & Firefox. However, I am not able to locate any documentation which states the behavior of the `url()` function when no argument is passed.

Please let me know if this is the correct behavior or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [by W3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#url-value), the url() function expects a string as a parameter. Here in your case `$scope.image_url` was resolved to an empty string, which is a legal [Relative URL](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#relative-urls), so browser will try to resolve this to a full URL, which in your case is `base_url + ''`.

You can verify that by change `$scope.image_url = '1'`, then you can see one request to http://yourdomain/1.

To prevent this I would suggest you to create a `fallback` directive to show a default image if you don't have a image for this record, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26208993/553073) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I think he's resolving your empty bind as `url(undefined)`.. So He'll try to resolve the URL `http://<domain>/path/to/your/page/undefined` .

Do you initialize `scope.image_url` on page load?

To prevent this, I suggest to bind the **entire** style attribute, and not only the `url()` ... If there is no "empty" `url()`, I think it won't load a random request... Or if the background is only static, use CSS classes instead of `style` attribute...